PrimeFaces FileUpload Not Working - Primefaces - 14.0.6, Tomcat - 10.1.31
I am using PrimeFaces 14.0.6, Java 17, Spring 6, and Tomcat 10.1.31, jakarta.faces (Mojarra) - 4.0.9. I am trying to implement file upload functionality using PrimeFaces, but when I upload the file and click submit, It does nothing, just clears the uploaded file.  Other xhtml pages are working fine.  I am facing issues only with upload functionality.
Here is my
typesUpload.xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"> 

    <ui:define name="content"> 
        <h1>File Upload Issue</h1> 

<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <h:messages id="resultMsg" errorClass="error-message" infoClass="info-message"/> 
    <div class="input-row"> 
        <div class="required">*</div> 
        <h:outputLabel id="fileLabel" for="upload" value="Excel File: "/> 
        <p:fileUpload id="upload" value="#{enumTypesUpload.file}" 
                      mode="simple" styleClass="file" update="resultMsg"/> 
    </div> 

    <div class="clear"></div> 

   <p:commandButton id="getFile" class="submit-button" value="Submit"
                             action="#{enumTypesUpload.upload}" ajax="false"/> 
</h:form> 
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>

Here is my
EnumTypesUpload.java
bean class:
package com.example; 

import jakarta.faces.application.FacesMessage; 
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext; 
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped; 
import jakarta.inject.Named; 
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent; 
import org.primefaces.model.file.UploadedFile; 

import java.io.Serializable; 

@Named 
@ViewScoped 
public class EnumTypesUpload implements Serializable { 

    private UploadedFile file; 

    public UploadedFile getFile() { 
        return file; 
    } 

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) { 
        this.file = file; 
    } 

    public void upload() { 
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded."); 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
        
    } 
} 

In my WebAppInitializer class which implements WebApplicationInitializer, I added
servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "native"). I also tried with auto but doesn't work.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Did you add multipart-config and other related tags of file upload in your web.xml file?
